# Non-square transfer matrix from square scattering matrix

Tags: scattering

I'm trying to construct the transfer matrix for an arbitrary system with 1 input and 2 outputs, like a splitter (shown below) or 1x2 multi-mode interferometer.  (Image borrowed from http://www.fiberstore.com/images/ckfinder/images/tutorial/1x2_Splitter.jpg)

[image: a busy cat]

Currently, I have the entire scattering matrix for my device:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_\text{in}^{(-)}\\
A_\text{out1}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{out2}^{(+)}
\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}
S_{00} & S_{01} & S_{02}\\
S_{10} & S_{11} & S_{12}\\
S_{20} & S_{21} & S_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A_\text{in}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{out1}^{(-)}\\
A_\text{out2}^{(-)}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where the $(+)$ and $(-)$ correspond to forward and backward propagating signals, respectively.  I am looking for a transfer-matrix $\hat{T}$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_\text{out1}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{out1}^{(-)}\\
A_\text{out2}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{out2}^{(-)}\\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
T_{00} & T_{01}\\
T_{10} & T_{11}\\
T_{20} & T_{21}\\
T_{30} & T_{31}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A_\text{in}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{in}^{(-)}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Likewise, I am interested in the inverse transfer matrix such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_\text{in}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{in}^{(-)}\\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
T_{00} & T_{01} & T_{02} & T_{03}\\
T_{10} & T_{11} & T_{12} & T_{13}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A_\text{out1}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{out1}^{(-)}\\
A_\text{out2}^{(+)}\\
A_\text{out2}^{(-)}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which I figured I could just get from the pseudo-inverse of the previous result.  Would this work?  In both cases I am having trouble finding $\hat{T}$ because I am moving from a scattering matrix with 3 variables and 3 equations to either (1) an overdetermined system with 2 variables and 4 equations or (2) an underdetermined system with 4 variables and 2 equations.

It seems that generating a transfer-matrix for such a splitter should be quite straightforward, especially since I already have the scattering matrix data.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured out what my problem is.  After some reading transfer matrices are just convenient rearrangements of the same information contained within a scattering matrix such that you can easily cascade the matrices and make the math a bit nicer.  However, for my purposes I can just write out the separate equations resulting from the 3x3 scattering matrices and solve the system brute-force.  Now I'm just evaluating all my cascaded components (with equal i/o's) via transfer matrices then manually linking them up to the splitters.

TLDR; don't need the transfer matrices, scattering matrices do just fine on their own.